# Issues with /dev/sda prevent system to launch

Tags: 14.04

as you see, there are errors during launching the system (if it's important: ubuntu 14.04, my laptop is Asus Zenbook UX32l), and yesterday I heard some "clicks" when system was running. Now it doesn't launchs at all.

My questions are: what should I do now? what is the cause of this problem?

just because I don't have enough reputation here now, but I want you to see the photo of system messages, this is the link to my [question with photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518383/i-have-some-problems-with-dev-sda-in-my-laptop/27518489#27518489) at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked up the model of your notebook and it would appear that if it is as originally sold, it may have either the 1TB hard drive or a 128gb SSD.  The symptoms you describe suggest a dying hard drive, which is consistent with very thin portable computers.  Hard drives are delicate machines under the best of circumstances, and so the thinner and denser the machine it is housed in, the less that exists to protect it if it is handled roughly.

Certainly I can offer you some shortcuts to diagnosing for certain that you need to replace the drive in your machine, but to cut to the chase, you probably need to plan to do that, and when you do, that you purchase solid state next time.  Supposing that your drive might be mSATA, rest assured you can purchase a 1TB in solid state for under $500, and in fact, you could probably tolerate something smaller in capacity and save a few dollars.  Now back to the matter of diagnostics.

The advice you've already received is good.  Yes, you can just boot your notebook to an external USB live Ubuntu boot medium such as that which you probably installed it with.  Alternately you can use an external USB cd/dvd drive to boot to a live cd/dvd.  Either will work.

Once you have booted to external media, you will want to open the included utility known as Disk Utility.  There you will see an area marked SMART, provided of course your dying drive supports that protocol.  If it does, you will not only be able to determine immediately if it is dying, but even what likely caused it and how long you have left to rescue any data you wish to save.

Rescuing your data will be easy once you are booted to this external media, provided of course that your personal data directories are not encrypted anyway.

Comment: ps: if you are using external media to boot your system for data recovery, you will almost certainly need additional media to copy your data off to, such as a network drive, thumbdrive or external hard drive.  I probably don't need to explain that, but I'm mentioning it just in case it's not obvious to you.